# My latex is not formatting correctly :(

Tags: formatting

[image: this is my text/code]

[image: But my output is not doing what I want :(]

Basically the text should be all the written text and then the 3 images but for some reason the program is printing the first table in the middle of the text.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: And never do ever make screenshots of source code!

Comment: Your question is very unclear, what is not working?  If you mean the table is too wide replace `[scale=1]` by `[width=\linewidth]` but why are you showing tables as images of monospace text files rather than typeset a latex table?

Comment: Your first table lacks a floating specifier (and you shouldn't use \\ to force line breaks)

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but please consider doing your tables as real latex tables instead of images. This way you avoid the ransom letter look of each table having a different font size.

Comment: I would focus on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8631/107497, which begins "do not use a floating environment [such as table] if you do not want it float".

Comment: Also check the spacing around punctuation marks, the space is sometimes on the wrong site